# Control 24VAC solenoid with arduino using a octocopuler and a Triac

Tags: arduino, opto-isolator, triac

Following a [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387080/driving-a-24vac-solenoid-with-arduino-using-a-octocopuler-and-a-triac) I implemented the following schematic on my PCB.

The schematic :

[image]
[image]

My PCB:

[image]

[image]

I have been unable to make it work, if I measure the voltage on j13 it's allways 25v, i know the controller is working because D2 Led is on for 5 seconds and then off for 5 seconds.

- If I remove R20 J13 is always 0v.
- If I remove the MOC3012 j13 is always 25v.
- I have replaced U2 and Q1 with brandnew ones just in case they where fried but it makes not difference

I have been scratching my head all day long trying to figure out what's wrong with my implemention but I can't find where is the problem.

My adrduino code :

```
void selfTest()
{
int counter = 0;

/* Clears the LCD screen */
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
lcd.print(F("Self Test"));

/* This routine never stops */
while (true)
{
    diagnostic.turnOn();
    delay(100);
    diagnostic.turnOff();

    /* Updates the counter test */
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(counter);

    /* Acoustic notification */
    beep();

    /* opens the valve and waits 5 seconds */
    openRelay();
    delay(5000);

    /* closes the valve and waits 5 seconds */
    closeRelay();
    delay(5000);

    /* increment the counter as 1 complete open/close cycle */
    counter++;

    diagnostic.turnOn();
    delay(100);
    diagnostic.turnOff();
}
}
```

Edit:

Added J12 which is the connection to the 24VAC power supply.

Comment: Are those pins on the microcontroller supposed to be bridged?

Comment: SOLENOID is connected to a microcontroller pin, VAC1 and VAC2 are connected to J12, a 24VAC power supply

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I guess if D2 blinks on/off it does not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change output circuit for inductive load (check the triac datasheet, you have 1 and 2 swapped). See Figure 8 in [MOC3012](https://datasheet.octopart.com/MOC3011-M...-Fairchild-Semiconductor-datasheet-627034.pdf) datasheet. Don't forget to remove R20.
- You might also need a snubber as on Figure 13 in [here](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MO/MOC3023M.pdf)

Comment: I have not yet connected any load, just my multimeter and it's always 25V when it shouldn't

Comment: Without load how do you expect MOC to be supplied with power? Through _voltmeter_?

Comment: the MOC is connected to the 24V power supply via VAC1 and VAC2 (J12 on the PCB photo), not solenoid is yet conected to the J13, just my multimeter

Comment: I don't see J12 on schematics. VAC1 stops at J13.

Comment: edited my question and added J12 schematic, it's connected to the power supply.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Once again, **VAC1 stops at J13 if there is no load connected.** It does not reach MOC pin 6 through R19

Comment: I'm not kidding you, but I'm learning electronics and I'm probably missing something obvious. From my understanding VAC1 is always connected between the power supply and the load (the solenoid) when the micrcontroller sets the MOC pin to HIGH the the TRIAC connects VAC2 from the power supply to the J13 closing the circuit and energizing the solenoid, like if it was a mechanic relay or at least it was the idea.

Comment: Ughh.. In order for triac to open the current must flow trough R19, into pin 6, through photodiode, out pin 4 and to gate 3 of triac. In order for current to flow there must be a voltage between VAC2 and pin 2 of J13. Without load there is no voltage, VAC1 is _not connected_ to circuit at all.

Comment: In that case ... I still don't understand why I'm measuing 24V between pin 1 and 2 of J13 without any load (when the micrcontroller sets the MOC pin to HIGH and when it sets the MOC to low) ?

Comment: Because your triac is connected upside down, when you added R20 you created permanently open path through. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/257761/187920) for very good description, then connect it as in Figure 8 in the link.

Comment: Note, that if you invert the triac you might even be able to see some voltage due to photovoltaic operation of photodiode, but it will never be fully opened until you connect the load and let current through.

Comment: I tried inverting the Triac and you were right, it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW I didn't see you updated your answer and I didn't remove R20 when testing the inverted triac and it still works, will look to implement figure 8 on the datasheet. I'm using a TVS diode to avoid using a snubber

Comment: In your circuit TVS connected across load. Snubber is installed in parallel to triac to suppress spikes that can propagate through R19 to the gate and latch triac in open state, eventually damaging it. This improves switching characteristics. Depending on your load you might not need a snubber. R20 serves no purpose in this circuit.